# How can I display all files in a web directory?

Tags: apache

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with Apache 2.4 and i want to make a folder which will contain all my PHP files that I am making for testing purposes. I created a Vhost for the folder and it works when i target the sepcific file in mind, in example :

> http:/phptestsite/some_random_php_script.php

When i go there the code (if it works ;) ) will execute, but I want to create a list of all php files (similar to that of a ftp site/listing) when i go to

> http:/phptestsite/

So that i do not have to manually type in everytime each individual php script I want to test, but just go to that vhost and click on the file.php I want to test.

Vhost conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/usrnname/PHPTest/
ServerName phptest
ServerAlias phptest
  <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All
         Require all granted    
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/username/PHPTest/>
           Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you add vhost configuration

Comment: Just did,sorry i forgot.

Comment: Have you tried to add `Indexed` to the `Options` parameter? This might help you [DirectoryListings](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `Options +Indexes` to list the directories

```
<Directory /home/username/PHPTest/>    
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```